# Mouse Movement + Key Press = Scroll

Tags: keyboard, mouse, mouse-scroll, mouse-wheel, remapping

I would find it very, very nice if I could obtain scroll functionality (vertical is most important) by moving my mouse, say, up and down while holding down a key.

I know scroll is normally obtained by mouse button presses `4` and `5`, but I don't have those keys. Can I map `mouse movement + key press` to obtain them?

Any other suggestions to the same effect would also be very welcome.

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something but why not scroll with the scroll wheel as normal people do :D ?

Comment: I'm the one missing something - the scroll wheel ;)